# search_s search_ext_s search_s methods of python-ldap library doesn't return any Success response code

Tags: python-ldap

I am using search_ext_s() method of python-ldap to search results on the basis of filter_query, upon completion of search I get msg_id which I passed in result function like this ldap_object.result(msg_id) this returns tuple like this (100, attributes values) which is correct(I also tried result2, result3, result4 method of LDAP object), But how can I get response code for ldap search request, also if there are no result for given filter_criteria I get empty list whereas in case of exception I get proper message like this 
ldap.SERVER_DOWN: {u'info': 'Transport endpoint is not connected', 'errno': 107, 'desc': u"Can't contact LDAP server"}
Can somebody please help me if there exists any attribute which can give result code for successful LDAP search operation.

Thanks,
Radhika

Answer (score 0, accepted):

An LDAP server simply may not return any results, even if there was nothing wrong with the search operation sent by the client. With python-ldap you get an empty result list. Most times this is due to access control hiding directory content. In general the LDAP server won't tell you why it did not return results.

(There are some special cases where *ldap.INSUFFICIENT_ACCESS* is raised but you should expect the behaviour to be different when using different LDAP servers.)

In python-ldap if the search operation did not raise an exception the LDAP result code was ok(0). So your application has to deal with an empty search result in some application-specific way, e.g. by also raising a custom exception handled by upper layers.